# Cambiar el layout de un fragmento al realiza clic en un botón

Tags: android

Tengo dos fragmentos. En el primero ha dos botones y me gustaría que dependiendo del botón que se pinche cargue un layout u otro en el fragmento de la derecha.

En uno de los onclick de un botón en la actividad tengo esto:

```
FrameLayout contenedor = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmento_derecha);

LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);

View viewinflado=inflater.inflate(R.layout.boton1,contenedor,true);
```

En el otro botón:

```
FrameLayout contenedor = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmento_derecha);

LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);

View viewinflado=inflater.inflate(R.layout.boton2,contenedor,true);
```

Sin embargo esto no realiza lo que estoy buscando. Infla bien un layout u otro al clickar un botón pero no quita los elementos del anterior layout. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que realizar un **[FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)**, para cargar  dentro del **[FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)** un **[Fragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html)** u otro  :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_contenedor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Por ejemplo, para cargar tu Fragmento que contiene el layout `R.layout.boton1` :

```
Fragment fragment = new miFragmentBoton1();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_contenedor, fragment).commit();
```

o tu Fragmento que contiene el layout `R.layout.boton2` :

```
Fragment fragment = new miFragmentBoton2();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_contenedor, fragment).commit();
```

Estas serían las clases `miFragmentBoton1()` que infla `R.layout.boton1`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class miFragmentBoton1 extends Fragment {

    public miFragmentBoton1(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout. boton1, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

y `miFragmentBoton2()` que infla `R.layout.boton2` :

```
public class miFragmentBoton2 extends Fragment {

    public miFragmentBoton2(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boton2, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora ya me carga el fragmento que deseo según el botón que pulso. Sin embargo al rotar la pantalla con uno de los fragmentos cargados me indica:  "Unable to start activity"

Comment: @adamista es importante revisar el LogCat, que error te muestra ahí con más detalle ?

Comment: Bueno esta pregunta creo que ya esta resuelta. Ok sería muy raro que no te muestre ningún mensaje en el LogCat,  si te indica en un dialogo "Unable to start activity" puedo asegurar se genera un NullPointer en tu Actividad , para activar el LogCat Primeramente:
Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor
después dentro de Android Device Monitor:
Window > Show View >  Elige LogCat  . Que te parece si agregas otra pregunta con el problema pero agregas el código de tu actividad que carga los fragmentos! =)