# onItemClick ¿Cómo puedo abrir fragments?

Tags: android

¿Cómo puedo abrir un fragmento con `onItemClick`, o voy mal encaminado? Los activity sin problemas, pero los fragments me da error.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.herprogramacion.restaurantericoparico.R;
import com.herprogramacion.restaurantericoparico.adapters.Calendario_Volley_Adapter;
import com.herprogramacion.restaurantericoparico.tabs.TabActual;
import com.herprogramacion.restaurantericoparico.ui.ActividadConfiguracion;


public class Frag_Calendario_Cadetes extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    Fragment fragment;

    // Atributos
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jornadas_list, null);

        TextView miTexto = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mi_java);
        miTexto.setText("CALENDARIO CADETES");

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);


        // Obtener instancia de la lista
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Crear adaptador y setear

        adapter = new Calendario_Volley_Adapter(getActivity());


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

                Fragment fragment = null;
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                switch (position){

                    case 0:
                        fragment = new TabActual();
                        break;

                    case 2:

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActividadConfiguracion.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        break;
                }

                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.swipe_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                }
            }

            private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
                return null;
            }


        });

        return view;
    }

    @override
    public void onRefresh() {

        if (swipeLayout!=null) {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            swipeLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
            swipeLayout.clearAnimation();
        }
    }

    public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cadetes, menu) ;
        return false;
    }

    @override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Esta es mi jornadas_list.xml que creo que es donde esta el error

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mi_java"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ALGO FALLA"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#db1616"
    android:gravity="center" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/calendario_row"
    android:divider="@drawable/linea"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp">



</ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

el logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                            Process: com.rafelcf, PID: 23169
>                                                            Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.franzyroy.black.side,
>   iconPack:com.franzyroy.black.side, fontPkg:com.franzyroy.black.side,
>   com.android.systemui=overlay:com.franzyroy.black.side,
>   com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
>                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                at com.herprogramacion.restaurantericoparico.fragments.Frag_Calendario_Cadetes$1.onItemClick(Frag_Calendario_Cadetes.java:77)

Comment: Rafael, revisa como se realiza la transacción de Fragments en esta pregunta:http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835/cambiar-el-layout-de-un-fragmento-al-realiza-clic-en-un-botón

Answer (score 1):

Esta sería la forma correcta para realizar la transacción para cargar tu clase Fragmento `TabActual()` ;

```
Fragment fragment = new TabActual();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.swipe_container, fragment).commit();
```

asegura que tu

```
FrameLayout
```

en verdad tenga el id:

```
swipe_container
```

y tu clase

```
TabActual()
```

, no contenga errores.

---

**Actualización:**

recuerda que la vista donde se realizaran las transacciones debe ser un `FrameLayout` :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Post 1 editado no se pero creo que el error esta en el jornadas.list.xml, ¿puede ser?

Comment: Es muy sencillo determinar el problema si se agrega el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat. Que mensaje se muestra ahí?

Comment: Esta en el post 1

Comment: la vista donde se realizaran las transacciones debe ser un FrameLayout no un SwipeRefreshLayout: