# Tengo este error al querer pasar de un Activity a un Fragment

Tags: java, android

Me dice que debo agregar el fragment a Manifest pero no me deja...

Este es el error en el logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.matias.finalcode, PID: 9941
                  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.matias.finalcode/com.example.matias.finalcode.Fragments.InicioFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3782)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3743)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4053)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4021)
                      at com.example.matias.finalcode.Bancos.Banco1$2.onClick(Banco1.java:99)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19757)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9941 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Y este es el botón en la Activity que me debería llevar al fragment

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Banco1.this, InicioFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            }
        });
```

Este es mi MANIFEST

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.matias.finalcode.InicioActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".SignupActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity" />      
        <activity android:name=".Bancos.Banco1">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Creo que lo pone claro, ¿has declarado el activity en el manifest.xml?

Comment: @Wyrncael El Activity Banco1 si esta en el manifest pero del Activity Banco1 quiero ir al fragment InicioFragment y el fragment no puedo ponerlo en el manifest... Por eso me da el error y el intent no me deja pasar de la Activity al Fragment :/

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes ponerlo en el manifest?

Comment: Porque es un fragment al que quiero ir y me da error al ponerlo en el Manifest

Comment: Échale un ojo a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6856/onitemclick-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-abrir-fragments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que asi no se inicia un Fragment, un Fragment es un componente de una Activity y necesita de ella para iniciarse. cuando haces `startActivity(intent);`Android espera que le pases una Activity y no un Fragment. De ahí que te de el error diciendo que necesitas declararla en el Manifest, ya que no la encuentra.

Para realizar transacciones de Fragments en tu Activity (como agregar, quitar o reemplazar un Fragment), debes usar las API de `FragmentTransaction`. Puedes obtener una instancia de `FragmentTransaction` de tu Activity como esta:

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();`

Luego puedes agregar un Fragment usando el método add() y especificando el Fragment que se agregará y la vista en la que se insertará. Por ejemplo:

`ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Un ejemplo de una clase Fragment seria la siguiente

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
}
```

}

Te recomiento que le eches un vistazo a la guía de desarrollo de Android que la tienes en español.

[Fragmentos | Android developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=es-419)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte amigo. Que tengas un buen día!!