# ¿Como hacer que se ejecute el OnCreate al llamarlo con un LayoutInflater?

Tags: java, android, layout

Tengo un problema al llamar mi layout dentro de otro con LayoutInflater.

mi actividad principal tiene un menú de botones que manda a llamar a otras activity, pero, al momento de llamar alguna actividad no entra el onCreate.

Esta es mi vista principal a la que llamo las otras vistas.

```
public class controladorDeVistas extends AppCompatActivity {
FrameLayout contenedorDeVistas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_controlador_de_vistas);

    contenedorDeVistas = findViewById(R.id.contenedorVistas);
    buscar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);

    buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
    public void onClick(View v)  {

    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda, 
    contenedorDeVistas, false);
    contenedorDeVistas.addView(view);
        }
    });
```

Esta es mi actividad que mando a llamar

```
public class agenda extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_agenda);
System.out.println("Prueba si entra el onCreate");
}
```

Ya probé varias formas pero solo me pinta lo que tiene el layout y no ejecuta ninguna función.

Comment: Para ir de una `activity` a otra, debes hacerlo mediante un `Intent`

Comment: Entiendo la forma de ir a otra activity con intent, pero lo que necesito es cargar una actividad dentro de un FrameLayout.

Comment: Un activity es una actividad individual no puede haber un Activity dentro de otro Activity o dentro de un fragment. O ejecutas el activity con un intent o lo que necesitas no es un Activity sino quizas un fragment

Comment: Espero esto sea lo que buscas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835/cambiar-el-layout-de-un-fragmento-al-realiza-clic-en-un-bot%C3%B3n @CristianRamírez

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Muchas gracias era casi lo que necesitaba en conjunto con la respuesta de Erick Silva, necesitaba un Fragment pero ahora tengo el problema que no se remplaza solo el fragment si no todo el activity, casi como el intent.

Answer (score 1):

El programa no está mandando a llamar a otras activities.

Para llamar otras activities tenes que usar `startActivity(...)` o `startActivityForResult(...)` de un `Context`.

```
buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
    public void onClick(View v)  {
        Intent intent = new Intent(controladorDeVistas.this, agenda.class);
        controladorDeVistas.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Notas adicionales:
controladorDeVistas es una clase => Las clases se inician con letra mayúscula.
agenda => lo mismo
agenda debe extender AppCompatActivity en lugar de Activity.
Como la llamada a `startActivity()` se hace dentro de un objeto anónimo (`new View.OnClickListener(){...}`) para obtener a una referencia al `Activity` que implementa el `Context`,  tenemos que anteponer el nombre de la clase contenedora al this: por ejemplo `ControladorDeVistas.this`

```
public class Agenda extends AppCompatActivity {
    ....
}

public class ControladorDeVistas extends AppCompatActivity {
   ....

    buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ControladorDeVistas.this, Agenda.class);
            ControladorDeVistas.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Entiendo esa parte gracias, pero, lo que necesito es llamar una actividad dentro de un FrameLayout, logro llamarla con layoutInflater pero no ejecuta lo que esta en el onCreate.

Comment: Con LayoutInflater no estás haciendo una llamada, estás instanciando un, o parte de un View. El View es la parte visual de un Activity donde está lo que se vé en la pantalla. El Activity es lo que se ejecuta. Por ahí si explicas lo que querés lograr, mas que como lo pretendes resolver, podrian surgir mejores alternativas de la que pensaste.

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan ya lo resolví.

Utilice un Fragment.